# Configuring 'AutoGenerateColumns' property of a DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, datagridview, windows-forms-designer

I have a datagridview configured to autogenerate columns based on my class (using databinding).

It works just fine for all my properties of type `string`. However, I have a property of an enum type, with a typeconverter to convert it to an image.

I'd like for my Grid's autogeneration of columns to produce a `DataGridViewImageColumn` instead of a `DataGridViewTextBoxColumn`.

The only DGV method that seems helpful is columns added.  However, you cannot set the column there, only get & modify.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2):

as far as i know, the AutoGeneration isn't very configurable
but you can make an alternative auto gen for yourself:

set autogen = false,
register to these events:

- OnDataMemberChanged
- OnDataSourceChanged

add a single function that will be triggered for both, which will create columns for the dataSource given:

- header = column name
- column type = according to what you want
- data binding = the column name
- etc.

Comment: can you add a sample how to create column in that case?